# Drop database from phpmyadmin 4.9.2 and its still connect

Tags: mysql, pdo

i delete a database name = test and its still connect , I used PDO connection here is my code PHP :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5aHi.png)

and when I tried to add a new database it doesn't connect ?

Comment: No images please, copy the code here

Comment: ok, the image is work now, you can  see the code ,thanks

Comment: No! don't put images with code, please edit your question and write the code

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)